# mssql удаление данных

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день 
есть таблица t1 и t2 в каждой из них есть столбец link 
как удалить из таблицы t1 все строки , в которых link равен link из t2
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для SQL Server будет так:

```
DELETE FROM t1 FROM 
t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.link = t2.link;
```